# Combining Data from Two Google Analytics URLs

Tags: google-analytics

Upon updating our website, we had a few URLs change.

/oldpage changed to /newpage

/oldpage has a 301 redirect to /newpage

The data in analytics shows up on /oldpage until we made the transition to /newpage, say on January 20th. So we see data on /oldpage up until the 20th, then the data flat lines. The data starts on January 21st for /newpage.

How can I change this data so they appear under 1 filter or are combined?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot change historical data in Google Analytics. You have 2 options:

- Live with it. Leave an annotation at the date the result flatlines so that other users know what happened; OR
- Add an advanced filter that rewrites `/newpage` to `/oldpage`.